# How to send data of a jquery table to sql

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery table with property set to sortable( I can drag and drop rows),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tblLookup1 tbody").sortable({
            items: 'tr',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },

            stop: function (e, ui) {
                $("#tblLookup1 tbody tr").each((idx, tr) => {
                    $("td:nth-child(4)", tr).text(idx+1);
                });
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
               
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now after sorting a column with the name preference gets updated, 1st row will have preference value=1, 2nd row =2 and so on...

Now these values are available until I refresh the page. So as to make permanent changes I want to update the database with the new preference values.
**This is a .net MVC ado based web app**
Ques) How can I store these preference values into some list and later pass on/post to sql database.

view file code

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Active</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (ViewBag.data != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in ViewBag.data)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.AutoID</td>
                                    <td>@item.Text<br </td>
                                    <td >@item.Active</td>                                      
                                    <td>@item.OrderBy</td>
                                </tr>

                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Store each value in a different input per row, all with the same name='OrderBy[]` - `<input name='OrderBy[]'`>` / wrap the whole table in a `<form>` and submit the form.    Some more info on posting array objects is here:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Use a for instead of a foreach with inputs or helpers inside the cell tags

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize or  https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray These can help you create the Object or Array to POST back to your script. The script will need to accept the POST and add it to the Data base or update the `OrderBy` column.